# how to query efficiently when i search in a model using a condition which can have many values?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, query-performance

I have two models `User` and `Type`. Each user can have multiple types. Consider the following example

```
sample_user(user)
  ----> football player(type)
  ----> actor(type)
  ----> buisness-man(type)
```

and similarly there are number of users present along with their types. There is another model called `Like`. The like model contains the type he likes most. It can be even his own type or the other type that he does not have. consider an example

```
sample_user(user)
  ----> cricketer(like)
  ----> actress(like)
  ----> buisness-man(like)
```

Now what i want to do is, the `sample_user` has 3 likes and i want to compare the likes of the sample_user with the types of other users and if any one of the likes of `sample_user` matches with any one of the types of other user, then i have to fetch that user. So how can i do this. please help me. I think this would take some time if the query is not efficient. so please help me. Sorry if the question is unclear. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with just SQL queries. You can do something like this

```
user1_likes = sample_user1.likes.pluck(:title)
user2_likes = sample_user2.likes.pluck(:title)

result = user1_likes & user2_likes

fetch user2 if result.present?
```